# How do ladder operators and number states act on multimode states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-optics

The ladder operators for number states, $\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger}$, and $\alpha_{\ell}$ have the following properties when working on mode $\ell$:
$$\begin{array}{l}
\hat{\alpha}_{\ell}\left|n_{\ell}\right\rangle=\sqrt{n_{\ell}}\left|n_{\ell}-1\right\rangle \quad \\
\hat{\alpha}_{\ell}\left|0_{\ell}\right\rangle=0 \\
\hat{\alpha}_{\ell}^{\dagger}\left|n_{\ell}\right\rangle=\sqrt{n_{\ell}+1}\left|n_{\ell}+1\right\rangle
\end{array}$$

And considering a pure wavefunction $\psi_{\ell}$, the expectation value
$$\left\langle\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}\right\rangle=\left\langle\psi_{\ell}\left|\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}\right| \psi_{\ell}\right\rangle$$
gives the number of photons in mode $\ell$. However, what would be the effect of $\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}$ on a wavefunction over some different mode $\ell'$? Put differently what would I get if I tried to calculate $\left\langle\psi_{\ell^{\prime}}\left|\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}\right| \psi_{\ell^{\prime}}\right\rangle$?

Comment: What is |psi_l> (with or without ')?

Comment: e.g. $|\psi\rangle_{\ell}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}|n\rangle_{\ell}+|n+1\rangle_{\ell}\right)$ (where I took the $\ell$ outside the bracket with the same meaning)

Comment: But if you have more modes you have to specify what the state is for *all* modes. And then you know what the operators do.

Comment: I consider mixed states using the density matrix $\hat{\rho}=\sum_{i} p_{i}\left|\psi_{i}\right\rangle\left\langle\psi_{i}\right|$

Comment: Say I want to calculate the expectation value of the operator $\widehat{N}:=\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}+\alpha_{\ell^{\prime}}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell^{\prime}}$. The expectation value of a general operator, $\hat{A}$, can be calculated as $\langle\hat{A}\rangle=\sum_{i} p_{i}\left\langle\psi_{i}|\hat{A}| \psi_{i}\right\rangle$. But that means that when calculating $\hat{N}$ I will get "expectation values" of $\alpha_{\ell^{\prime}}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell^{\prime}}$ over $\psi_{\ell}$ and vice versa.

Comment: are you using $a^\dagger_\ell$ or $\alpha^\dagger_\ell$?

Comment: It's meant to be $\alpha$. I wrote in unicode and used a program to convert...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multimode states are product states
$\vert n_1n_2\ldots,n_{\ell'}\ldots,n_\ell\ldots \rangle =\vert n_1\rangle\otimes\ldots \vert n_{\ell'}\rangle 
\otimes \ldots \otimes \vert n_\ell\rangle\otimes \ldots $ and the working assumption is probably that if $\langle n_1\ldots,n_\ell=0,\ldots\vert\psi_i\rangle = 0$ then $\hat \alpha_\ell \vert\psi_i\rangle=0$ so $\langle \hat \alpha^\dagger_\ell \hat\alpha_\ell\rangle=0$.

Comment: Now that I think about it, that does make sense, since $\hat{\alpha}_{\ell}\left|0_{\ell}\right\rangle=0$ as written in my question.

Comment: so then it's a matter of figuring out if you multimode state has anything in mode $\ell$.

Comment: And $\alpha_{\ell}$ commutes with $|n\rangle_{\ell^{\prime}}$? So that I can write $\left\langle\left. n\right|_{\ell}\left\langle\left. n\right|_{\ell^{\prime}} \alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell} \mid n\right\rangle_{\ell^{\prime}} \mid n\right\rangle_{\ell}=\left\langle n\left|\alpha_{\ell}^{\dagger} \alpha_{\ell}\right| n\right\rangle_{\ell}\langle n \mid n\rangle_{\ell^{\prime}}$

Comment: yes.  $\hat \alpha_\ell$ and $\hat \alpha^\dagger_\ell$ only "see" the part of the state that refers to mode $\ell$.

Comment: Okay, then I think it adds up. Thank you for the help.